# perlbrew install of perl-5.32.1 fail porting/libperl.t on macOS

Tags: perl

```
perlbrew install perl-5.32.1
```

fails on macOS Big Sur (11.3.1)

The end of the log file includes this:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
porting/libperl.t                                                (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 35 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=2678, Tests=1208628, 934 wallclock secs (75.33 usr 15.27 sys + 505.35 cusr 79.82 csys = 675.77 CPU)
Result: FAIL
make: *** [test_harness] Error 1
##### Brew Failed #####
```

It also fails in the same way when I try to install perl versions 5.32.0 and 5.30.3

Any clues as to why the perl installation is failing? And how to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to instal a local copy, or in the system? Likely unless you install a local copy in a different folder, it's a no go. The MacOS depends upon perl with the system install. Try installing a local copy in your home dir.

Comment: As I understand it, perlbrew installs a local copy in ~/perl5/perlbrew. That's where this failed installation went anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62439696/223226 looks identical.

Comment: Can you try update `patchperl` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65332078/2173773) and then retry the install?

Comment: You can ignore this failure. perl5-porters is likely to remove this test since it isn't useful for end users https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/21677

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore this failure. perl5-porters is likely to remove this test since it isn't useful for end users. See https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/21677.